# Compare two txt files in Python

Tags: python, file, compare

I have two input files:

one.txt:
a
a
a
a
a
b
b
b
b
b

two.txt
b
b
b
c
b
a
a
c
a
a
b

I have the following code:

```
with open('two.txt', 'r') as file1:
    with open('one.txt', 'r') as file2:
        difference = set(file1).difference(file2)

difference.discard('\n')

with open('difff.txt', 'w') as file_out:
    for line in difference:
        file_out.write(line)
```

And I am getting output as:

c

But I want to have something like:

c

c

Can someone help me in solving the issue?

Comment: Converting to sets gives you just `set(file1) = {'a', 'b'}` and `set(file2) = {'a', 'b', 'c'}`. Which is why you get one `'c'` as output. You can get the set difference (which you have), and then iterate over `file2` as a list of the elements in the file and print out or save to a variable every time you see an element from the set difference.

Comment: Please, describe what you want to be done in plain English, only then show you code. In the current question we cannot determine if the first lines (a for text1, b  for text2) need to be in the result. Neither we can know if in case of the following two files  ("a a", "a a a") the awaited result is "a" or "".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `collections.Counter`:

```
with open('one.txt') as f1, open('two.txt') as f2:
    one = Counter(f1.read().split())
    two = Counter(f2.read().split())

with open('diff.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    for c, i in (two - one).items():
        outfile.write(f'{c}\n' * i)
```